# Handling exceptions in MQL4

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

In the `Java` language one can handle exceptions with a `try`-`catch` mechanism.

Does it exist any similar behaviour in **`MQL4`**?

This code throws the error '**`array out of range`**' in the `Close[bar]` expression and I cannot handle it properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
bool isBarClosed( int bar ) {
    bool   barClosed  = true;
    double closePrice = Close[bar];
    int    error      = GetLastError();

    if ( error == 4202 ) {
        barClosed = false;
    }   
    return barClosed;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an official documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

**`MQL4`** has no syntax support for a construct alike a `try/except/finally` or `try/catch` use-case in python / java and alike languages.

### How to handle exceptions?

Assume there are no compile-time errors.

The run-time errors are hard to be handled, some even cause the software to crash.

One could and rather shall proactively sanitize the MQL4-code with a due type-checking and use-case pre-validations so as to prevent exceptions.

Exceptions to this are **`dbPool`** operations, which may, under some conditions, "legitimately" fail to yield an expected result.

A **`GetLastError()`** ( if it was cleared a-priori the exception itself ) may serve as an almost-post-mortem identification, not as an exception handler.

### 4202? Not your problem, Bro'

```
_LastError == 4202 ... does not explain the trouble                <<< stdlib.mqh

4202
    ERR_OBJECT_DOES_NOT_EXIST
    Object does not exist
```

Your problem seems to be related with **`bar`** "pointing" outside of the `TimeSeries`-reverse-stepping-index of **`Close[]`** values.

**`0 <= aBarPtrIDX < Bars`**

### Next target? A `Close[aBarPtrIDX]` misconcept

After some time spent in `MQL4` domain, one becomes familiar with a few contradicting facts. One of potential surprises is, that a current bar, the 
"hot-zero" **`[0]`**, contains **`Close[0] == Bid`** during it's all live-life-span.

After the running bar gets terminated by `aNewBarEVENT` ( signalled by a `Volume[0] == 1` ( or `Volume[0] < aPreviousVolume_0` -- a safer mode for a case, the `MQL4`-loosely-coupled event-loop has missed a few `quote`-arrivals during it's busy-episode )), the `Close[1]` represents the last-visited price during the respective `Bar`-period and `Close[0]` keeps surfing on the always-changing **`Bid`** price